# Why doesn't the bundle work in my asp.net mvc project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundles

I have created a bundle of js files ("bundles/js") in which I included all js files that were required for the page.

```
  @Scripts.Render("/bundles/js")
```

and after rendering it throws error for above line :

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

and after rendering it appears like

```
<script scr="/bundles/js">
```

but nothing works on page.

I have commented the references to all js files and put the render but it doesn't work.

I have include optimization dll in project, in web.config and also added bundlesConfig class

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include("~/Content/js/jquery.min.js", 
                                                                 "~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/owl.carousel.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/smooth-scroll.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/waypoints.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/jquery.counterup.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/menumaker.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/jquery.appear.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/jquery.countdown.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/price-slider.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/jquery.elevatezoom.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/theme.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.flash.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/pdfmake.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/vfs_fonts.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.html5.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.print.min.js",
                                                                 "~/Content/js/blockUI.js"));
        }
    }
```

and then registered in application_start

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }
```

Previous sequence of files was:

```
<script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/menumaker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/price-slider.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/theme.js"></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/blockUI.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you set [BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs#L12)?

Comment: no not yet i have

Comment: I did and it doesn't work, in js it throws error upon rendering

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Does it make any difference if you have `~`? `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")`

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add into web config
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web> 

public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)          
{   
  //Enable bundling
  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You missing a tilde in `@Scripts.Render("/bundles/js")`

Try - `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")`